# Granular level Authorization which can sustain in future

Tags: rest, security, oauth-2.0, authorization

Currently we have OAuth2 as Authorization for microservices which works like this:

1. Clients need to register with clientName, scope information and get client id and client secret.
2. To access any API they get token from Authorization server using a Proxy API
3. Use this token to call actual API, in API code we validate the token by calling another proxy API
4. This proxy API is built on top of actual OAuth Process APIs (PingFederate APIs)

Problem:

1. PingFederate APIs does not validate the scope implicitly, we are adding an explicit logic in proxy to get the scopes validated
2. We don't want validate proxy API to sit in the code, there should be security layer above code
3. Better client management

We want a solution that provides fine grained access of resources which does not sit with the code and has better client management process.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by validating scopes? What do you have in mind for fine grained? Need an example use case or something. Also, better client management is unclear. What are your current pain points for client management? How do you envision it would work ideally? There are many possible routes to take here from maybe a change to your configuration and processes to looking at rbac, abac, pebac, and the many other kinds of x-based access control

Comment: While validating a token to access a specific resource, that time should be validated whether the token was generated with the specific scope needed for this resource. As an example, token was generated with READ scope on resources and access write resource. This is happening as of now because OAuth does not validate scope while validating a token.
For client management, currently, we need to raise a ticket to get the client registered, updated and deleted. That ticket goes to Ops then owner and then client gets created. How can we make this proces bit smooth.

Comment: That is what the OAuth 2 scope claim is for. "Tokens
   represent specific scopes and durations of access, granted by the
   resource owner, and enforced by the resource server and authorization
   server." What you're referring to is the enforcement via the resource server. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-1.4

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing some definition in your setup:

**API GATEWAY**

This should perform work before APIs are called. It should handle client specific security differences, then forward a JWT access token to APIs.

**APIs**

Every API should verify a JWT access token and perform claims based authorization. But they should not need to deal with aspects such as browser cookies. There should be no need for an API to call a proxy API, which feels like a bottleneck.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

Clients should be registered here. APIs also interact with this component, at the very least to download token signing public keys.

**ENTITLEMENT MANAGEMENT**

If you want access control to sit outside the code, then have a look at systems such as Open Policy Agent. An API (or the gateway) can forward its JWT, or the claims payload, so that some authorization decisions are externalized.

**FINALLY**

When an OAuth solution is difficult to manage, that often originates from trying to manage volatile domain logic in the generic security components. The best solutions use a smart design that finds a good balance ...